# Using google secret manager with react native app

Tags: react-native, expo, google-secret-manager

I need to secure my firebase config file which include the API keys of the project's database so I searched for too long and I have figured that there is no way to do that but storing these sensitive keys with google secret manager but there is no documentation or tutorial about how to use Google Secret Manager with react native expo
so if any one has experience with this issue please help me to do that

I tried searching in google and another resources and did not find any helpful info

Answer (score 0):

**Overview -**

Google secrets manager is a cloud product offered by Google Cloud Platform (GCP). You are not finding a ReactNative package to work with this product because React Native is a front end library for mobile. We normally handle secrets and API keys on the backend layer of an application. That way, it is not exposed to the consumers of our application.

If you were to handle secrets in your mobile application, anyone who uses the mobile application would have access to your database credentials.

However, you may not need GCP for your current situation, depending on what you are attempting to do. We can also configure FireBase directly in the ReactNative application and control the access through the project settings. There is NPM packages that support this and documentation showing examples.

**Solution**

1. If you require a Secrets Manager, one potential solution is to create a backend service that handles all of your database connections. This way, you can secure the credentials in a way that is not visible to your end users. You can do this using tools like GCP, AWS, or Azure.
2. If you only need to configure a FireBase connection with your ReactNative application, you can use [React Native Firebase NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/app). You can find the [documentation here](https://rnfirebase.io/).